# 419 Ajax Error on Laravel 5.6 - Edited

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have multiple page with Laravel 5.6 on PHP 7.2

Up until this morning when I signed on using another computer all was fine. I have my CSRF tokens in the head and grab them for the ajax just as stated in the documentation. Again - pages worked until I signed in under a different computer.

Now I get 419 errors on my ajax. I look through my GIT commits and see nothing changed in regards to javascript and the head template.

This is obviously (to me) a token mismatch or a auth issue. But how do I debug? No errors are generated server side, and the error coming back from the ajax is

> exception:"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException" 
> file:"E:\InetPub\LegacyLogin\LegacyLogin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php"
>   
> line:203
>   
> message:""

I have:

- checked timeout in config/sessions.php
- checked csrf headers against
  documentation
- tried putting the CSRF token in a hidden input
- deleting my cookies
- logging out / in
- restarting IIS

And I am at an impasse.

Here is the code that has worked for the past 3 weeks until today when I logged in from another computer.

Javascript/Jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/app/personrep",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: ()=>{            
        //window.location='/myinfo';
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

In app.blade.php template head:

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Can someone point me in a direction. I have even taken one of the files (the view) and changed it for EVERY suggestion on here and Laracast...

Update:
The exclusion offered below worked... So I have 2 json strings - one works as it should, the other causes a problem with the CSRF, it appears.

--- I got the system back working. But I have no idea what happened. I am storing a JSON string in a MySQL DB using Models, and earlier, I manually removed a object from it. 
The I validated the JSON before manually inserting it into the DB again, and the strange thing is that it affected multiple pages. If it were a JSON error it should have showed up during the rendering of the views.

As I am relieved that I got this working, I need to know what happened before this app goes into production. The JSON is very large, but I will post it if it would help someone help me diagnose the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. With one of my ajax calls during testing, I mistakenly inserted a "_token" property into the object. This worked until I logged in to another computer, apparently generating a new token.

I pass the object back and forth from the view, to the controller, and model - a neat package...

So what I have learned and want to pass on is that a "_token" in the data property of an ajax call
ie:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/app/personrep",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
    data: {"_token":"asfbgasdfhba"},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: ()=>{            
        //window.location='/myinfo';
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Will ALWAYS override the token set in the Header.....

Answer (score 2):

Try this to see if it is csrf causing the problem. In VerifyCsrfToken.php in your middleware, exclude that route, i.e.

```
protected $except = [
        //
    '/app/personrep',
    'app/personrep'
];
```

Comment: I will try that, I know now how to cause the error - I posted in the main post

Comment: The exclusion worked. I have 2 json strings - one workes as it should, the other causes a problem with the CSRF, it appears.